# Do version strings like G930FXXU1BPLB, hold any retrievable information?

Tags: android, android-version, android-firmware

I have searched google for similiar strings but found no information about anything else but people on google forums talking about flashing.

How can I as developer extract useful information from version strings like G930FXXU1BPLB?

Answer (score 1):

It is Samsung Firmware, This firmware has version number PDA - G930FXXU1BPLB. Always Samsung release with PDA version number each updates.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case it seems to be a samsung firmware-version.

You can find information about it on the [samsung-firmware.org page](http://samsung-firmware.org) and search for it. It seems to yield the current OS-version (6.0.1 marshmallow), Build-Date and possible device models.

I don't know if it has any valuable information beside OS version, maybe in a particular problematic build version you might find a bug report somewhere, but I deem that unlikely. Most devs would probably search for the device name if available (Nexus 6, galaxy note 7, sony xperia etc.).

I don't know if those version strings are exlusive to samsung though.